# Dialogue box for permission not appearing. using PermissionsAndroid React-Native

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

```
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    {
      title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
      message: 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
        'so you can take awesome pictures.'
    }
  )
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED || granted === true) {
   console.log("succeed")        
  } else {
    console.log("location denied");
  }
}
requestLocationPermission();
```

whenever i run the code it always show "location denied" on console. I am using react-native version 0.55.

Comment: What is the targetSDK version in your gradle file?

Comment: targetSDK version is 22.

Comment: Make it 23 or more.

Comment: still didn't work for me.